# PHP Failed to connect to mailserver at mail.OURDOMAIN.com port 25 .... However, I can telnet test mail through

Tags: php, winapi, smtp

There's a million posts on this error out there on the web:
Failed to connect to mailserver at "mail.OURDOMAIN.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Here's the facts:

Before our site was forced to join the companies large SMTP server pool, our configuration was working fine (using a SMTP server managed by another group). As soon as we pointed the SMTP server entry to the new SMTP server, we get 'failed to connect' issues.

I can telnet to mail.OURDOMAIN.com 25 and successfully send a test mail through manually -- it should work.

I have the correct settings in php.ini and I've restarted the webserver.

I also have used ini_set() for these settings and get the same results.

Very odd... any suggestions here?

I'm using this code to test:

```
<?php 
//change this to your email. 
$to = "joe.guy@OURDOMAIN.com"; 
$from = "joe.guy@OURDOMAIN.com"; 
$subject = "Hello! This is HTML email"; 
$message = "hello";
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers); 

echo "Message has been sent....!"; 
?>
```

Here are my php.ini settings:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.OURDOMAIN.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = joe.guy@OURDOMAIN.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Comment: maybe you have the outgoing port 25 blocked

Comment: did you run your telnet test from the same host as the web server?

Comment: - port 25 not blocked
- Yes, telnet test was conducted through the webserver (which is auth'd for SMTP relay, confirmed by telnet testing).
- If I use a different SMTP server, it works. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ip address of your domain instead of the name. That has worked for me a number of times.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = 127.0.0.1
```

ie: your own ip smtp server ip adress

Comment: "I can telnet to mail.OURDOMAIN.com 25", so the dns works... +1, but it's worth a try

Comment: Port 25 not blocked because:
A) The application worked when I pointed to another SMTP server (I'll test with gmail tomorrow)
B) I *can* send email through the target SMTP server via telnet

Comment: So close.... when I enabled sendmail flags in php.ini, I no longer get the connection failed error, but I don't get the mail delivered either :)